# Is there a better way to access the first element selected with a JQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a better way to write this so I don't have to use the [0] and so I can access the text by the JQuery Text instead of innerText ? I don't want to use innerText for Cross Browser compatibility .

```
$('#' + controlBestPractice)[0].innerText
```

Comment: `$('#' + controlBestPractice).text()` [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: sachleen is right # means it is a id, there must be only one item with that id so there is no need to use .first() or :first. [0] is for accessing pure dom object instead of the jQuery object not the first selected element.

Comment: @OnurTOPAL # only means that the selector starts with an id.

Comment: @Christophe As far as I know it not start with id it means it s equal to that id same as CSS selector and for the performance it uses css selector or document.getElementById(). not other fancy jquery selector (not sure about the older browser.) and it only returns only one element even there are more, please check the following link.
http://jsfiddle.net/3XmFj/

Comment: @OnurTOPAL, see the example in my answer. There could be more to the selector than just one ID. From this, all we know is that the parent element has an ID. Nothing about its children that the selector could be selecting.

Comment: @OmurTOPAL how about this: $("#myForm input") (where controlBestPractice="myForm input")

Comment: if you are using the access the first child of the element with given id I would use $("#id").children().first(). 
not 1 : you can also use "#id > " selector but complex selector text might cause search the whole DOM, first accessing with id better choose.
not 2 : you can also filter children using .children("input") or .children(".className") format an so on.

Comment: @OnurTOPAL you're absolutely correct... but that's not the question.

Comment: Come on the question is answered don't beat a dead horse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [first](http://api.jquery.com/first/) if your selector returns more than one element (we don't really know what is inside `controlBestPractice`, e.g. it could be `#div-id p`):

```
$('#' + controlBestPractice).first().text()
```

As bhamlin pointed out in comments, it appears that you are using id selector, so there *should* be only one element, so this should work:

```
$('#' + controlBestPractice).text()
```

Comment: since the selector is by `id`, the `first()` isn't necessary *in theory* since there should be only one.

Comment: @bhamlin not true, it could be a selector that starts with an id.

Comment: @Christophe true, I've edited my answer to cover different cases, as we don't really know what selector is used

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
$('#' + controlBestPractice + ':eq(0)').text();
```

or

```
$('#' + controlBestPractice).first().text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you guys doing `.first()`? It's an ID there should only be one.

```
$('#' + controlBestPractice).text()
```

will work just fine

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ojojih)

I suppose you might need `.first()` in the following situation but that'd just be a bad (confusing) way of selecting:

```
<div id="foo">
    <div class="bar">a</div>
    <div class="bar">b</div>
    <div class="bar">c</div>
</div>

controlBestPractice = "foo .bar";
$('#' + controlBestPractice).text(); // returns abc
$('#' + controlBestPractice).first().text() // returns a
```

Comment: same comment as the others: the question doesn't say that the selector is an id, it only says that the selector starts with an id.

Comment: @Christophe yeah I had just thought of that. That'd be a confusing way of selecting though.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to add the `[0]` on the end since it is a selector by id.  The `#` denotes you are selecting by id and since id's are unique jQuery will only return a single element.

Comment: The jQuery selector returns an array. An array does not have the javascript `innerText` property so you have to use `[0]` to select the HTML element in the array (it only has one) which has the `innerText` property.